# How can I run this task in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this Df in pyspark.

```
cod, date    , value_1, value_2, value_3
1  , 2021-03 ,       0,       3,       3
2  , 2021-04 ,       2,       0,       0
3  , 2021-05 ,       3,       3,       3
4  , 2021-03 ,       0,       0,       0
```

I need to add a column, that counts the zeros that are in the value columns by cod, and that it remains like this.

```
cod, date    , value_1, value_2, value_3, new_column
1  , 2021-03 ,       0,       3,       3,          1
2  , 2021-04 ,       2,       0,       0,          2
3  , 2021-05 ,       3,       3,       3,          0
4  , 2021-03 ,       0,       0,       0,          3
```

I use pyspark SQL.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check for 0s in the value columns, and count them by rows.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

value_columns = ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3']

df.withColumn("new_column", sum(F.when(df[col] == 0, 1)\
    .otherwise(0) for col in value_columns)).show()

+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------+
|cod|   date|value_1|value_2|value_3|new_column|
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------+
|  1|2021-03|      0|      3|      3|         1|
|  2|2021-04|      2|      0|      0|         2|
|  3|2021-05|      3|      3|      3|         0|
|  4|2021-03|      0|      0|      0|         3|
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------+
```